# What is the difference between similar installed PHP packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, php

For instance, on Ubuntu Xenial, I need to install the `mbstring` PHP extension. I issue the command `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` to do so.

With `dpkg`, I can see two packages related to the module: [php-mbstring](https://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/xenial/php/php-mbstring) and [php7.0-mbstring](https://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/xenial/php7.0-mbstring).

Did they get installed together? And if they're similar packages, how can I know which one is being used (or which one to use)?

Comment: Use `apt show php-mbstring`. The answer is in the package description.

Comment: *This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default PHP version (currently 7.0)*. Does that mean `php-mbstring` is the module and `php7.0-mbstring` the parent implementation of MBSTRING on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Debian changes to another version of PHP (8.0), php-mbstring will pull in the correct package automatically.

`php#.#-mbstring` has the code.

`php-mbstring` has no code, and simply depends upon the correct package with code. This is called a *transitional package* or *dummy package* or *metapackage*.

The same method of a generically-named metapackge to manage automatic upgrades is used to upgrade your kernel.